# Getting an error message, 'There is no ViewData item with the key 'Reason' of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' for the DropDownList in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm very new to the ASP.net framework, and will appreciate it if somebody could help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm trying to create a dropdownlist for the table field, "Reason" from a SelectList using asp.net mvc 3.5 (C#).

In my View code I used MVC HTML method Html.DropdownList:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Reason", Model.Reason)%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("Reason", "*")%>
```

In the Model class I added the list of 'reasons' in the code:

```
namespace Appointments.Models
{
    public class AppointmentFormViewModel
    {
        public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> ReasonValues
        {
            get
            {
                return new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    { string.Empty, string.Empty },
                    { "Add/Drop", "Add/Drop a Course" },
                    { "Academic Diff.", "Academic Difficulty" },
                    { "Academic Plan", "Academic Plan" },
                    { "Other", "Other: Fill out below" }
                };
            }
        }
        public SelectList Reason { get; set; }

        public AppointmentFormViewModel(Appointment appointment)
        {
            Appointment = appointment;
            Reason = new SelectList(ReasonValues, "Key", "Value", appointment.Reason);
        }
```

In the Controller the code is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Reason"] = new SelectList("ReasonValues");
    return View();
}
```

When I'm debugging the code I'm getting an error message, 'There is no ViewData item with the key 'Reason' of type 'IEnumerable'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

So you have a controller action which returns a view but you are not passing any model to this view:

```
return View();
```

And yet your are trying to use `Model.Reason` in your view. That's not allowed.

So the first thing is to have your controller action return a model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Appointment appointment = ... // get an appointment from somewhere
    // instantiate your view model
    var model = new AppointmentFormViewModel(appointment);
    // pass the view model to the view
    return View(model);
}
```

The second thing is to use a strongly typed helper in your view (`DropDownListFor`) which uses as first argument a scalar type property that will harbor the selected value of the dropdown (assuming here that `Appointment.Reason` is a simple property type like `string`):

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Appointment.Reason, Model.Reason, "-- Reason --") %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Appointment.Reason, "*") %>
```

And now you can get rid of the `string.Empty` value in your `ReasonValues` dictionary as we can specify it directly in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should return an instance of AppointmentFormViewModel from you controller. Then you should create a view that is strongly typed (of type AppointmentFormViewModel as well). Then you can use: Model.ReasonValues in your view.